# Potion looks like colored glass bottle when I use my resource pack

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

[image]

If I use my resource pack in Minecraft, potion looks like colored glass bottle. My resource pack adds extra textures like coca-cola texture that works with CustomModelData. Also my coca-cola texture is colored too.
This is code in json file:

```
{
    "parent": "minecraft:item/handheld",
    "textures": {
        "layer0": "minecraft:item/potion"
    },
    "overrides": [
        {
            "predicate": { "custom_model_data": 1},
            "model": "item/coke"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What are you specifically asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make the bottle the overlay, just the liquid inside it.